# Variables initialized in a TextFixtureSetup not read by a IEnumerable-using test

Tags: c#, nunit, ienumerable

I'm writing my first test fixture in NUnit, and I am using an external file to load match criteria. Something like:

```cs
List<string> stringList;

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void LoadResource(){
    stringList = new List<string>;
    string line;
    using (StreamReader file = new Streamreader("file.txt"){
        while ((string line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {stringList.Add(line);}
    }
}
```

When I first do a normal test on a single item, stringList has been filled by LoadResource, and the test runs fine:

```cs
[Test]
    Public void Test0(){
    string line = stringList[0];
    //specialized tests here
    GenericTest(line);
}
```

But the following test returns a null exception when accessing stringList:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(){
    foreach (string line in stringList){
        yield return line;
    }
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("GetStrings")]
public void loopedTests(string line){
    GenericTest(line);
}
```

What am I missing here? I'm assuming there's either something about enumerator that means they have to be contain valid references at the time the class is created, but why - and how best to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/664018) in the NUnit framework. The `TestCaseSource` method will get invoked before the `TestFixtureSetup` method.

You could do some lazy loading in `GetStrings` instead of using the `TestFixtureSetup` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(){

    if (stringList == null)
       LoadResource();

    foreach (string line in stringList){
        yield return line;
    }
}
```